# Is it correct to use -1 as a size for an output SqlParameter to retrieve a VARBINARY(max) value?

Tags: t-sql, ado.net, varbinary, sqlparameter

I have a stored procedure with an `OUTPUT` parameter of the `varbinary(MAX)` type:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[StoredProcedure1]
  ...
  @FileData varbinary(MAX) OUTPUT
AS
...
```

I don't know what would be the actual size of the returned data, so I can't use an exact value for the `size` parameter of the `SqlParameter` constructor. From the other hand, the actual size could be more than 8 Kb (if it matters).

When I create a `SqlParameter` without declaring a size:

```
        var fileDataParameter = new SqlParameter("@FileData", SqlDbType.VarBinary)
            { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };

        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.Add(fileDataParameter);

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        var fileData = fileDataParameter.Value as byte[];
```

I'm getting the following exception on the `command.ExecuteNonQuery()` line:

> Additional information: Byte[][0]: the Size property has an invalid
>   size of 0.

So I need to specify the `size`. Some people recommend to pass `-1` as the value of the size:

```
            var fileDataParameter = new SqlParameter("@FileData", SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1)
                { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };
```

But I can't find a solid description of this thing neither on the [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hex23w80%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), nor anywhere else.

In my case, the maximum size of data returned in `@FileData` parameter isn't more than 10 Mb.

So the question is **if passing `-1` as a size to a `SqlParameter` mapped to a `varbinary(MAX) OUTPUT` parameter is the correct approach**, for example, from the performance perspective?

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/jeffwids/nvarchar-max-parameters-need-the-size-set-to-1

Comment: @Khurram, Thank you. However, this post doesn't contain any clarification on the usage of -1, just '_you have to set the size to -1 to get it to work_'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the MSDN documentation. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399384.aspx
- See "Using Large Value Type Parameters" section

Passing a "-1" is the correct approach for "MAX" value size.  Since it's a VarChar, it won't add add or return any extra chars, only the ones you set in that column. So it should be very efficient.

Comment: Thank you for the link and explanation!

Comment: Thanks  Is - 1 also correct for, type varbinary???